# How I can use the result of SELECT statement in ALTER TABLE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some properties. I would like use these properties to create some columns in another table (ALTER TABLE).

The follow SELECT statement result in multiple results:

```
SELECT property FROM table1 GROUP BY property;
```

Result example:

- firstName
- lastName
- address
- phone

For each result of select statement above, perform:

```
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD property boolean null;
```

How do?

Comment: You can compile an `ALTER TABLE` statement as a string (for example, in a stored procedure). Then you can `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` it.

Comment: This rather suggests your data structure could be [normalised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) better.  Can you talk us through what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @eggyal Is well normalised. I got all values ​​of a <select> tag from third party website and inset in table1. I use the group_by clause (in SELECT statement) to elimine duplicate properties (has some). Finaly, I want insert all properties (returned by select) with column in table2. In my system, I only use table2. Perform this operation with PHP is easy, but I want learn how do this with SQL statements only. (sorry for my inaccurate english)

Comment: @ThiagoRodrigues: it's *possible* to do in SQL (like @Shedal suggests, you'd have to use prepared statements - but given they can't contain multiple SQL statements, you'd have to loop over a cursor constructing each `ALTER TABLE` statement in turn, preparing then executing it... it'd be easier to do it in PHP).  However, I still maintain your data structure may not be right.  **Why** do you want these property columns in `table2`?  Can you not JOIN with `table1` and undertake whatever tests you need as required?

Comment: @eggyal For performance and simplicity issues I think is best in table2. I'll try to do what Shedal said.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for postgres. With little modification you can use it for mysql too.

```
DO $$
DECLARE row_results record;
BEGIN FOR row_results IN
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema='public'
        AND table_type='BASE TABLE'
        AND table_name = 'table1'
    LOOP
        EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE table2 ADD COLUMN %I boolean NULL', row_results.column_name);
    END LOOP;
END$$;
```